# How can I stop the Enterprise Library caching block from persisting changes to data I've retrieved from it?

Tags: wpf, caching, enterprise-library

What an awkwardly worded question, you're thinking?

When my application loads, it goes to the database and gets several different lookup tables worth of data and creates .NET Lists for each one and puts them in cache. For example, "Status".

List at this point:
On,
Off

When I retrieve the List of Statuses from the cache, I add another item to the List, "Choose One" and the set it as the ItemsSource of a ComboBox. At no point do I put the new List, now containing "Choose One" in addition to the list of statuses back into the cache.

```
List<ContractStatus> contractStatuses = (List<ContractStatus>)this._cacheManager["CurrentContractStatuses"];

        ContractStatus contractStatus = new ContractStatus
            {
               ContractStatusDescription = "Choose One", ContractStatusId = 0 
            };
        contractStatuses.Insert(0, contractStatus);
```

List at this point:
Choose One,
On,
Off

Yet if I go to another screen and come back, the screen's load routine pulls the list of statuses from the cache, and Choose One is already in the list. So when the routine adds "Choose One" I wind up with:

Choose One,
Choose One,
On,
Off

Is this by design? How in the world do I tell it to quit?

Answer (score 0):

The Cache Manager is returning a *reference* to your `List<ContractStatus>`.  This reference points to the object in the cache.  You are then inserting an item into the same List as is in the cache.

Is it possible to cache a version of the List that includes "Choose One" so that you are only reading the List from the cache?  If so then that should avoid the "issue" you are seeing.

If you do need to manipulate the List from the cache without modifying the List in the cache then you should clone the List before manipulating it:

```
List<ContractStatus> contractStatuses =      
    (List<ContractStatus>)this._cacheManager["CurrentContractStatuses"];

// Clone the list (but not the items)
List<ContractStatus> newStatuses = 
    contractStatuses.ConvertAll<ContractStatuses>(item => item);

ContractStatus contractStatus = new ContractStatus
{
    ContractStatusDescription = "Choose One", ContractStatusId = 0 
};

newStatuses.Insert(0, contractStatus);
```